# How to separate redux reducers that rely on each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I have a small app where the user is presented a small list, that she can dynamically filter.

So I thought my state would look like :

```
{ data: [], filters: {}, filteredData: [] }
```

..which already is a bad idea probably.

I also have only one reducer so far, that responds to the actions :

- *UPDATE_FILTERS*
- initial *DATA_RECEIVED* (only once on the page load).

My reducer looks like this :

```
import {UPDATE_FILTERS, DATA_RECEIVED} from '../actions/actions'

function getFilteredDataRows(filters, data){

    const distanceMin = parseInt(filters.distanceMin) || 0;
    const distanceMax = parseInt(filters.distanceMax) || 9999999999;
    const location = filters.location || '';
    return (
        data
        .filter((swim) => swim.location.toLowerCase().includes(location.toLowerCase()))
        .filter((swim) => swim.distance > distanceMin)
        .filter((swim) => swim.distance < distanceMax)
    );
}

const filterReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case UPDATE_FILTERS:
            const newFilters = Object.assign({}, state.filters, action.filters);
            return { filters : newFilters, data: state.data, filteredData: getFilteredDataRows(newFilters, state.data)};

        case DATA_RECEIVED:
            return {filters : state.filters, data: action.data, filteredData: getFilteredDataRows(state.filters, action.data)};
        default:
            return state
    }
}


export default filterReducer;
```

And all of this works. But to me, it also stinks. 
I have followed the redux tutorials (the one of Dan. with Todo's)

**I would like to be able to separate my reducer into two:**

- FilterReducer (filter updates)
- DataReducer  (filteredData updates)

But the 2nd one relies on the first, I donT know how to do this in a clean way.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks promising : http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers

Comment: & https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers

Comment: can you share actions code ?

Comment: @Aaqib nothing special in the actions.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** listen for the same action in multiple reducers.

Listen for the `UPDATE_FILTERS` action in both `filterReducer` and `filteredDataReducer`.

In filterReducer, modify the filters part of the store.

In filteredData reducer, modify the data part of the store.

**filterReducer.js:**

```
const filterReducer = (state = [], action) => {
   switch(action.type){
        case UPDATE_FILTERS:
   return Object.assign({}, state, filters: action.filters);
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**filteredData.js:**

```
const filteredDataReducer = (state = [], action) => {
switch(action.type){
        case UPDATE_FILTERS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, filteredData: getFilteredData(action.filters, state.data));
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: but how do i make sure that the filteredDataReducer will be called after the FilterReducer ?

Comment: You can't. And you don't have to. Since you use the new `filters` which is passed with the `UPDATE_FILTERS` action (and not relying on store).

Answer (score 1):

IF those are the real needs and not some simplification, I will no use Redux at all but just manage state in React.

To your question:

There shouldn't be `filteredData` in the state, only the data and the filter.

The `getFilteredDataRows` method should be called from the render function of the react component that displays the data or from `mapStateToProps`

see [the Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components) for Implementing Container Components where his `getVisibleTodos` is like your  `getFilteredDataRows`

Comment: Thanks ziv! that indeed helps with the state structure issue i have. What about the two reducers tho? it s true that i donT need redux for this, but how would we do it in redux?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your first line of pasted code.

You keep in the state the data and the current filter. Filtered data is derived state (meaning it can be calculated from other pieces of state) and should be "calculated" in your React component. If neither `data` or `filter` changes, `connect` won't re-render your component.

So move that `getFilteredData` into a selector that receives the whole state and returns the specific data your UI needs, instead of storing it.

Since you didn't show any React code using that data I can't help you further. For complex selectors, you will end up looking into `reselect`, which is nicely explained in the Redux docs:

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html